# integer winding number algorithm with edge cases

Tags: python, algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I want the [winding number](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0103/algorithm_0103.htm) of a closed, piecewise-linear path (eg a polygon) about a point, but in addition, I want to detect when the path passes through the point. For this reason, I double the standard winding number. For a non-intersecting polygon with CCW orientation, the value will be:

- 0 if the point is outside the polygon
- 1 if the point is on an edge or vertex of the polygon
- 2 if the point is in the interior of the polygon

And similarly in other cases. (EDIT: [image of a few examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzgnV.jpg))

Every algorithm I've found fails when the point is on an edge or vertex.

My other requirement is that it has to give exactly correct results when all of the inputs (ie, the coordinates of the point and the vertices of the path) are integers. So this pretty much precludes trig functions or square roots, and division would have to be used carefully.

I do *not* need to handle degenerate paths that have two consecutive coincident points, or a 180-degree turn.

Anyway, I think I have a solution. However, it seems a bit inelegant, and I'm not confident that it's correct. (I really confused myself about what happens when the point is on a vertex.) Here it is in python:

```
def orient((x,y), (a0,b0), (a1,b1)):
    return cmp((a1-a0)*y + (b0-b1)*x + a0*b1-a1*b0, 0)
def windingnumber(p0, ps):
    w, h = 0, [cmp(p, p0) for p in ps]
    for j in range(len(ps)):
        i, k = (j-1)%len(ps), (j+1)%len(ps)
        if h[j] * h[k] == -1:
            w += orient(p0, ps[j], ps[k])
        elif h[j] == 0 and h[i] == h[k]:
            w += orient(ps[k], ps[i], ps[j])
    return w
```

[Link to a version with comments and unit tests.](http://pastebin.com/XiQwP8rF)

I would like a link to a correct algorithm, or some confirmation that my algorithm is correct, or a test case where my algorithm fails. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your assumption is wrong.

The winding number is not defined for points on the contour. (The integral is not well defined, in particular).

If you follow the same path twice you get twice the winding number. So if your assumption that the number will be 1 if the point is on the countour were true, then that would actually imply that the winding number if you go once is 1/2, but this is clearly wrong, because the winding number is always an integer.

Comment: Oh yes you're absolutely right, the number I want is more properly an extension of the winding number as it's normally defined. I think it's a pretty intuitive and consistent extension, but yes it's not the normal definition. Possibly I should call it by a different name.

Comment: except, I don't see a definition here... It is always 1 if the point is on the contour. That's not consistent at all. What if the curve passed through the point and then winded around it 10 times. Is it still 1... What I am saying is that yeah you can define your thing to be the winding number if not on the curve and whatever else you want if on the curve - but that's not gonna be helpful in any way

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, I figured the definition would be obvious, though a bit hard to state. If two edges pass through the point, the "modified" winding number at that point would be 2 (assuming it's not inside anything else). Here's an illustration of a few various values:
http://imgur.com/cDc6o

Comment: It's still not clear to me when you take it to be +1 and when -1...
The thing about winding number is that it allows you to compute it by using only local information (differential in the angle) and then integrate it. I don't see how you would determine the sign +1/-1 using only local information.

Comment: Well, I'm not *too* familiar with the contour integral definition, but the way I think about it is, if you send a train off along the path starting from your position, and turn to face it until it returns to you, then if you've turned 180deg CCW, it's +1, and if you've turned 180deg CW, it's -1.

Anyway, if you think this is a bad definition, that's fine, don't trouble yourself with it. I'm certainly not suggesting people adopt it, I just wanted it for myself!

Comment: This definition is ok. The problem is that you can't use it to compute the number... It can be much more complicated curve so that it's not obvious whether you turned CCW or CW. In fact the definition of CCW vs CW is through the sign of the winding number. (when the point is not on the curve)